# Magento 2 product import website id not updating

Tags: product, import, websites, import-products, bulk-actions

I'm importing products using csv. Using default method of magento. My csv file is below.

```
sku,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,product_type,categories,name,description,short_description,weight,product_online,tax_class_name,visibility,price,special_price,special_price_from_date,special_price_to_date,url_key,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,base_image,base_image_label,small_image,small_image_label,thumbnail_image,thumbnail_image_label,swatch_image,swatch_image_label,created_at,updated_at,new_from_date,new_to_date,display_product_options_in,map_price,msrp_price,map_enabled,gift_message_available,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,page_layout,product_options_container,msrp_display_actual_price_type,country_of_manufacture,qty,out_of_stock_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,allow_backorders,use_config_backorders,min_cart_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_cart_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_on_stock_below,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,website_id
testimport2,,Default,simple,Default Category/Kitchen Appliances,test import,"<ul><li>Shape: Tapered towards the point</li><li>Double cut, single cut and spiral cut</li><li>Uses: For filing holes, mouldings and half round grooves</ul>",File Round Bastard 100 mm Sleeve,1,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",10,,,,testimport2,,,,sale.png,,sale.png,,sale.png,,,,,,,,Block after Info Column,,,,Use config,,,,,,,,,1000,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,10000,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1
```

Product import working properly but website Id is not assigned. So products not showing in frontend. Please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Admin panel select category menu in select all products,click the action in Update all attributes and click the checkbox and click the save button.

[image]